# 64-bit Compliant issue Google Playstore while uploading the apk

Tags: android, gradle, google-play-services, 64-bit

I recently get this error from google play console stating that

"**This release is not compliant with Google Play 64-bit requirement.The following APKS are available with 64-bit devices but they only have 32-bit native code**".

So I found the solution in google support and I am writing this piece of code in my **defaultconfig** in build.gradle

```
 defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.abcdef"
    multiDexEnabled true
    ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64' //This line added
}
```

**Note->My project is a hybrid project and not native**

And after analyzing my apk after build I see two folders in lib directory i.e x86 & armeabi-v7a. There is no x86_64 & arm64-v8a directories present

So I am having a confusion that the APK That I have build is only 32 bit apk or will support both 32 and 64 bit. 
It is having **.so** files also.

Its is just a query as from august 1st google play will not take apps with 64-bit compliance as stated in their documentation.

Comment: Have you solved your problem, please share it with us

Comment: No in my project I am using IBM Mobile First studio maybe it is because of this. I will search more I am not sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is option in android studio to analyse APK. By this analysis you can confirm about what architecture (32/64 bit)  your APK is supporting. Follow the below link having complete steps,

https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit

Comment: I am having confusion regarding that documentation only. I go through the documention and then I am facing this issue

Answer (score 1):

I am using mobile first development MFP-STUDIOS-7.1.0 so by configuring the project with latest ifix of MFP7.1.0 I was able to solve this problem by using MobileFirst Platform Studio  7.1.0.00-20190730-1558